# Error al resolver: com.google.android.gms: play-services: 15.0.1

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas noches, solicito ayuda con este error.

//Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms: play-services: 15.0.1//

**necesito usar com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1 PERO al usar Gradle sync me sale el error antes mencionado solicito la AYUDA!!**

```
Estoy usando Android Studio 3.1.3
```

**Este es el build.gradle(Project:)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven{
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Este es el build.gradle(Module:)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "menpaqfast.menpaqfastconductor"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHiy6.png
```

Comment: Hello Bro, sorry but this page is only for Spanish Language, then you need translate his question and maybe we can help you, or if you want can come here [https://stackoverflow.com/] this site is in English... good Luck

Comment: Buenos días Sr.JJ gracias por la observación tengo un erro que se produce  y no me reconoce esta librería de play services //Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms: play-services: 15.0.1//

Comment: Estoy Usando Android Studio 3.1.3 //                                           build.gradle(Project:) classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4' classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'                             build.gradle(Module:)   //compileSdkVersion 28  // minSdkVersion 19 // targetSdkVersion 28 //buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

Comment: y se me presenta el error que esta en la fotografía, quedo agradecido por su ayuda

Comment: Debes editar la publicacion y ponerla en español. usa el boton [edit], arreglala y despues podremos ayudarte

Comment: Use **com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1**